# Display is juping all the time

Tags: kubuntu, display

Ladies and Gentlemen,
My problem is not a flickering display, it's more that the diplay content jumps all over the place. If I change the resolution and change it back again, the problem is solved until the next restart, but it reappears there. At the moment I have solved the problem by using the Xrenderer with 48Hz. This way I don't see anything from the login screen (because of the jumping image), but as soon as I have logged in, I have a normal image. If I switch to 60HZ or another renderer, the problem reappears after a restart, even after logging in. I use a Medion laptop (Akoya e3222) with an Intel Pentium Silver n5030 and Kubuntu 21.04 with the latest updates.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like an unsupported (or broken) mode on the actual hardware, or a disagreement between the list of hardware modes and what you're asking for.

Comment: Exactly, there seems to be a mismatch somewhere, I was just hoping that since it works pretty well with the Xrenderer and a low Hz number, I could maybe manually edit something to use the monitor at 60 Hz without problems. Thanks for your Imput.

Comment: I think maybe i should say this also, when i am using an other renderer and change the Resolution the Problem isn't there even if i change the resolution back. But when i reboot makes it unuseable till i get to Xrenderer and 48Hz for a nearly usable state.

Comment: After updating to kubuntu 21.10 all Renderer work with 48 Hz except at the first login screen. it thair a way to force the first login screen to use a specific refresh rate? Is their also a way, o read the supported Refreshrates of the display? I think 60 Hz should be OK because Windows should use it.